# preg_split is case insensitive with special characters

Tags: php, regex, string

I'm working on a script which splits string (of restaurant menu) by capital letter. Unfortunately in czech language some of the words begins by special character with diacritics. Splitting dishes by "common" capital letters works just fine, but my regular expression is case insensitive for some special characters and it splits the string with eg. š when it should split it only by Š. Strangely enough, some of the special characters works just fine, the only problematic letter so far is š/Š.
Could anyone help me please?

```
$dishes = preg_split('/(?=[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÁČĎÉĚÍŇÓŘŠŤÚŮÝŽĹÔÄËÏÖÜŸ])/', $dishes); 
print_r($dishes);
```

Above code returns

```
Array
(
    [0] =>
    [1] => Vepřová plec na paprice s těstovinami
    [2] => Domácí sekaná s bramborovou ka
    [3] => ší
    [4] => Těstoviny s rajským jablkem, olivami a žervé
    [5] => Domácí sekaná s e svíčkovou omáčkou
    [6] => Uzená kýta s čočkou na kyselo a vejcem 
    [7] => Vepřové  nudličky se zeleninou a rýží
    [8] => Pečená vepřová plec na medu a pivu s bramborami
    [9] => Plzeňský gulá
    [10] => š
    [11] => Hovězí zadní se svíčkovou omáčkou, citron, brusinky, 
    [12] => šlehačka
)
```

(don't mind the first empty row)
Thank you!

Comment: You should use `/u` modifier. Try `$dishes = preg_split('/(?=[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÁČĎÉĚÍŇÓŘŠŤÚŮÝŽĹÔÄËÏÖÜŸ])/u', $dishes);`.

Comment: Does it work if you use '\u0160' instead of 'Š'?

Comment: Make it generic: `preg_split('/(?=\p{Lu})/u', $dishes);`

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: If the goal is to match only specific alphabet letters, then `\p{Lu}` may overmatch.

Comment: I would like to make it generic, unfortunately your code (Lucas) doesn't split it at all. Adding /u doesn't help either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you handle Unicode input data with regex in PHP `preg` functions, remember to use `/u` regex modifier:

```
$dishes = preg_split('/(?=[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÁČĎÉĚÍŇÓŘŠŤÚŮÝŽĹÔÄËÏÖÜŸ])/u', $dishes);
```

**Note that you need to save the PHP files with UTF8 encoding!**

This will make the regex engine treat the input as a Unicode string, and will correctly process the regex pattern containing other than ASCII characters.

If you need to match *any* Unicode uppercase letter, (as LucasTrzesniewski mentions in the comment above) you can use the `\p{Lu}` Unicode category class:

```
$dishes = preg_split('/(?=\p{Lu})/u', $dishes);
```

Note that sometimes you do not have to use `/u` modifier. See [Daniel Klein's comment](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php#107498):

> It is not a requirement, however, as you may have a need to break apart utf-8 sequences into single bytes. Most of the time, though, if you're working with utf-8 strings you should use the `'u'` modifier.
>
> If the subject doesn't contain any utf-8 sequences (i.e. characters in the range 0x00-0x7F only) but the pattern does, as far as I can work out, setting the 'u' modifier would have no effect on the result.

And more warnings from [hfuecks](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php#54805):

> Regarding the validity of a UTF-8 string when using the /u pattern modifier, some things to be aware of;
>
> 1. If the pattern itself contains an invalid UTF-8 character, you get an error (as mentioned in the docs above - "UTF-8 validity of the
>      pattern is checked since PHP 4.3.5"
> 2. When the subject string contains invalid UTF-8 sequences / codepoints, it basically result in a "quiet death" for the preg_*
>      functions, where nothing is matched but without indication that the
>      string is invalid UTF-8
> 3. PCRE regards five and six octet UTF-8 character sequences as valid (both in patterns and the subject string) but these are not supported
>      in Unicode ( see section 5.9 "Character Encoding" of the "Secure
>      Programming for Linux and Unix HOWTO" - can be found at
>      http://www.tldp.org/ and other places )
> 4. For an example algorithm in PHP which tests the validity of a UTF-8 string (and discards five / six octet sequences) head to:
>      http://hsivonen.iki.fi/php-utf8/

So, trying

```
$dishes = preg_split('/(?=\p{Lu})/u', $dishes);
```

might be enough for your case depending on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Damn, I used your (resp. Lucas' code) it didn't split at all, but I removed the "u" and it appears to be working fine. Thanks! :) What do I do now, do I flag this as approved, even though it solved my problem only partialy?

Comment: Do you say `$dishes = preg_split('/(?=\p{Lu})/', $dishes);` works for you? Are you breaking the UTF8 string  into bytes?

Comment: I added some more information on the `u` flag usage, hope it helps.

Comment: I'm not sure, I had some problems with special signs in general. The goal of this is just to fill tons of dishes in database so it's just working with strings and as you can tell, I'm not an expert, especially when regex is involved :)

Comment: Ok, I am sorry, my mistake, it's not working after all, when I use `$dishes = preg_split('/(?=\p{Lu})/u', $dishes);`, it doesn't split at all, when I use `$dishes = preg_split('/(?=\p{Lu})/', $dishes);` it doesnt split by any special characters (Š,Ž,Č,...). What do you mean by breaking the UTF8 string into bites?

Answer (score -1):

I saved the PHP file as UTF-8 when I should have saved it as Windows-1250. Saving it as Windows-1250 solved the problem.