# Regular expression change the text, when it shouldnt

Tags: php, regex, character-encoding

This is very strange and i cant find something similar on the internet.

I got a table of strings in greek characters that contains alot of special chars, so i wanted to remove 'em.

```
function clean($string) {
   $string = preg_replace('/([$@!\?!\+\#\%\^\*\[\]\<\>\;\:\'\"\`\~\,\?\_\=\«\»])+/', ' ' ,$string);
   $string =  preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',$string);
   return $string;
}
$prok=clean($row['name']);
echo $row['name'].'-'.$prok;
```

This is working ok except when the character `Π` is inside the string.
If so the `Π` is replace with a questionmark.

[image: example]

Does anyone have an idea what the problem could be ??

Comment: It is really strange, there are so many questions like this on SO... Use `/u` modifier when declaring a regex that is intended for use with Unicode strings. `'/([$@!\?!\+\#\%\^\*\[\]\<\>\;\:\'\"\`\~\,\?\_\=\«\»])+/u`. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32843335/3832970).

Comment: You're escaping more than you need to, http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html. `In most regex flavors, the only special characters or metacharacters inside a character class are the closing bracket (]), the backslash (\), the caret (^), and the hyphen (-).`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `mb_ereg_replace` to support multibyte:

```
function clean($string) {
   $string = mb_ereg_replace('/([$@!\?!\+\#\%\^\*\[\]\<\>\;\:\'\"\`\~\,\?\_\=\«\»])+/', ' ' ,$string);
   $string =  mb_ereg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',$string);
   return $string;
}
$prok=clean($row['name']);
echo $row['name'].'-'.$prok;
```

Or use the `/u` modifier for unicode strings:

```
function clean($string) {
   $string = preg_replace('/([$@!\?!\+\#\%\^\*\[\]\<\>\;\:\'\"\`\~\,\?\_\=\«\»])+/u', ' ' ,$string);
   $string =  preg_replace('/\s+/u', ' ',$string);
   return $string;
}
$prok=clean($row['name']);
echo $row['name'].'-'.$prok;
```

Comment: `/u` didnt work , but `mb_ereg_replace` worked like a charm after i removed the seperators ! thanks !